# Grub install faild.How could I fix this problem

Tags: grub-efi

cannot set efi variable to boot0000
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHomh.png)

The ubuntu still can boot, but cannot enter the Desktop environment normally

[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLaKs.png)

How to fix this？